# ¿Cómo añadir un cero a la diferencia de horas y minutos cuando tienen un solo dígito?

Tags: sql-server

En la consulta de sql a traves de case usando len veo si los datediff que me dan las horas o minutos tienen solo un dígito, de ser así, que me concatene un 0 al principio, pero solo se lo añade a horas y no a minutos, alguien tiene alguna idea o ve mi error.

```
CASE
 WHEN LEN(cast(cast(CAST(DATEDIFF( MINUTE, INICIO, FIN) /60 AS DECIMAL(15,2))as decimal(15,2)) 
 as integer)) = 1 THEN

CONCAT('0' ,cast(cast(CAST(DATEDIFF( MINUTE, INICIO, FIN) /60 AS DECIMAL(15,2))as 
decimal(15,2)) as integer) , ':' , 
cast((cast(cast(datediff(MINUTE,INICIO, FIN) as decimal(15,2))/60 as decimal(15,2))-
cast(cast(cast(datediff(MINUTE,INICIO, FIN) as decimal(15,2))/60 as decimal(15,2)) as 
integer))*60 as integer) , ':' , '00')

WHEN LEN(cast((cast(cast(datediff(MINUTE,INICIO, FIN) as decimal(15,2))/60 as decimal(15,2)) - 
cast(cast(cast(datediff(MINUTE,INICIO, FIN) as decimal(15,2))/60 as decimal(15,2)) as 
integer))*60 as integer)) = 1 THEN
CONCAT(cast(cast(CAST(DATEDIFF( MINUTE, INICIO, FIN) /60 AS DECIMAL(15,2))as decimal(15,2)) as 
integer) , ':' , 
CONCAT('0',cast((cast(cast(datediff(MINUTE,INICIO, FIN) as decimal(15,2))/60 as 
decimal(15,2))-
cast(cast(cast(datediff(MINUTE,INICIO, FIN) as decimal(15,2))/60 as decimal(15,2)) as 
integer))*60 as integer) , ':' , '00'))
ELSE CONCAT(cast(cast(CAST(DATEDIFF( MINUTE, INICIO, FIN) /60 AS DECIMAL(15,2))as 
decimal(15,2)) as integer) , ':' , 
cast((cast(cast(datediff(MINUTE,INICIO, FIN) as decimal(15,2))/60 as decimal(15,2))-
cast(cast(cast(datediff(MINUTE,INICIO, FIN) as decimal(15,2))/60 as decimal(15,2)) as 
integer))*60 as integer) , ':' , '00')


END TIEMPO_REAL
```

En este caso INICIO Y FIN son datetime.

Comment: Pregunta no relacionada con la respuesta: por qué necesitas esos CAST anidados? Y lo otro, ¿sería más sencillo -y barato- si pones esos datediff en una variable y la reusas en vez de calcularlo ocho veces?

Comment: Me parece que es mucho más simple algo así   `right('00' + cast(datediff(MINUTE,INICIO, FIN) as varchar),2)`

Comment: Lo de la variable no lo tuve en cuenta, haré el cambio, con respecto al cast, para que me salga el resultado que buscaba, tuve que añadirlo, debido a que con el primer cast solo me aparecía un entero sin el decimal, ejemplo 7.00, y luego de usar el cast 7.50, esta así mas por un prueba y error.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho lo acabo de intentar, pero al convertirlo a varchar se pierde el calculo que hago y el resultado no es el mismo.

Comment: José, la idea que lo anterior lo apliques luego de cualquier calculo, tu pregunta apunta a como agregar un 0 a los minutos y eso es lo que hace el código independientemente si los minutos tienen uno o dos dígitos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería mucho más fácil si aprovechas que tienes los tipos de datos correctos para poder hacer un poco de aritmética temporal en vez de estar haciendo malabares con las cadenas.

```
SELECT
        --Opción resumida
        STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),FIN-INICIO,114),1,2,RIGHT( 100 + DATEDIFF(hh,0,FIN-INICIO), 2)),
        --Opción explícita
        STUFF( CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),DATEADD( SS, Y.Segundos, 0),114), 1, 2, RIGHT( 100 + DATEDIFF(hh,0,DATEADD( SS, Y.Segundos, 0)), 2)),
        --Resultado en tipo Time
        TIMEFROMPARTS( Y.Segundos/3600, --Horas
                        (Y.Segundos % 3600) / 60, --Minutos
                        Y.Segundos % 60, --Segundos
                        0, --Fracción de segundos
                        0) --Precisión
                        AS ResultadoEnTipoTime
FROM   (VALUES ( CAST('20210913 10:00' AS DATETIME),  GETDATE() )) AS X(INICIO, FIN)
CROSS APPLY( SELECT DATEDIFF( SS, INICIO, FIN) AS Segundos) Y;
```

Comment: Luis, esta super interesante, me solucionó el problema del los minutos, pero si quiero añadirle un 0 también a las horas, como haría, o tienes alguna documentación para guiarme de como hacerlo, agradecería que me la compartieras.

Comment: Acabo de agregar una opción que sirve pero solo si la diferencia en horas es menor a cien.

Comment: Muchas gracias Luis, me sirvió mucho.